# How Can I Call Multiple JavaScript Functions In Onclick Event for Submit Button?

Tags: javascript, html

Please how can I call these JavaScript Function for an Onclick Even.

Few Tips

Below is the submit button script;
`<button data-uifm-tabnum="0" class="rockfm-txtbox-inp-val btn" type="submit" data-val-btn="Submit" data-val-subm="Sending" onclick="javascript:rocketfm.submitForm(this);return false;" >Submit</button>`

Below is a Single Onclick Function that submit form -1st Function;
`onclick="javascript:rocketfm.submitForm(this);return false;"`

Below is the redirect Function I would like to add as the second function -2nd Function:
`top.location = 'https://google.com';`

I need help with code sample on how to execute 1stFunction, followed my the 2nd function.

Thank you.

Comment: I would give that button an id, then `document.getElementById('idHere')` on it, then assign the `.onclick = function(){}` to that, keeping my JavaScript separate from HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Just string them all together:

```
    <button data-uifm-tabnum="0" 
class="rockfm-txtbox-inp-val btn" type="submit" data-val-btn="Submit" data-val-subm="Sending" 
onclick="javascript:rocketfm.submitForm(this);top.location = 'https://google.com';return false;" >Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked but not satisfied because the parent page now automatically redirects even without the form page being filled. Is there any further assistance how to prevent the parent page from redirecting if the submit button is being clicked without the form page filled?

Comment: And moreover I noticed that the form submit action did not complete before is redirected because I didn't get the submitted data. So apparently the redirect button didn't let the form submit function complete the action. Pls Any further solution will be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That's a new problem.  Please post a new question

Comment: Please I am unable to ask a new question. Can you kindly help me with a javascript that can completely perform the submit and pass redirect function to the parent page on clicking submit on the Iframe Page?

Comment: If you are using an iFrame, you might want to include the relevant parts of you HTML markup since that makes it easier to help you.  also, it is probably better to use event handlers for your button, rather than including the JS inline with the button.  If you are using some sort of form validation it sounds like you want to a). validation the form, b) submit if valid and then c) redirect the window ?

Comment: Yes you get what I was trying to do @sscotti but I am implementing an external form builder of this. Looking at my code , can you provide me a more comprehensive tutorial with a code example? The function process I need is: Validate form >>  Submit Form then  >> Redirect  to https://www.google.com.